# How can I reference a project from 2 other projects, but build it with different nuget packages each time?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I have the following (simplified) setup in my solution:

- **Legacy API:** uses a nuget package in version 1
- **New API:** uses the same nuget package, currently also in version 1
- **Shared project:** referenced by both APIs, also uses the same nuget package in version 1
- everything is using net6.0 (C#10)

Now I want to do the following:

- Keep Legacy API unchanged, i.e. nuget package v1
- Update new API to nuget package v2
- Make the shared project compatible with both APIs

What I did so far:

- Duplicate just the `.csproj` file for the shared project and modify the nuget packages, so I now have

  - Shared.V1.csproj, using nuget package v1
  - Shared.V2.csproj, using nuget package v2
- The legacy API references Shared.V1.csproj, whereas the new API references Shared.V2.csproj

  - Done like this: `<ProjectReference Include="..\xyz\Shared.V2.csproj" />`
- The code in the shared project contains directives in some places where the behavior changed. This is done by defining a constant in each of the .csproj files and then using them like shown in the below example

Example

```cs
#if V1
// do stuff in the old way
#else
// do stuff in the new way
#endif
```

There are some problems:

- it feels like I'm doing it the wrong way (after reading the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs)
- it duplicates the projects in my solution, but the underlying files are actually the same. This can be confusing.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You can make project be compatible with V1 and make V2 backwards compatible with V1 by using package validation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/package-validation/baseline-version-validator

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your solution. I have successfully used the same technique a number of times now: multiple csproj files that reference the same source files and define some preprocessor directive; source files that differ slightly in some places depending on the preprocessor directive.

Comment: A couple of suggestions (if you do not employ them already):
1. make the csproj duplication and source file reuse obvious by putting the source files in a non-project folder and explicitly import them with `<Compile Include=... />` into each project. 2. keep each project file in its own folder so that the builds do not collide. 3. keep the "duplicated" csproj files consistent by extracting all common properties, items etc. into a .props file and import that into each csproj

Comment: @svenhuebner Thanks, those are great suggestions. I actually faced the issues that you described, so moving the files into separate folders helped. I'll make sure to apply your other suggestions as well.